# Creating a QVector of QLabels in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap, qlabel, qvector

I am trying to create a QVector of QLabels.

I am not sure how to go about this. I have declared my QVector like this: `QVector<QLabel> labels`

inside my .cpp file I want to set each label to a pixmap. Should I initialize all the instances through a for loop first?

Inside my constructor:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < usrinput; i++)
  {
     labels.append(new QLabel);
     setplayerpiece(i);
  }
```

I have a function outside of the constructor that sets each QLabel to an image:

```
   void CentralWidget::setplayerpiece(int tk)
{
  if (p[tk]->setpiece() == 0)
  {
    labels[tk]->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/hat.png"));
  }
  else if (p[tk]->setpiece() == 1)
  {
    labels[tk]->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/car.png"));
  }
  else if (p[tk]->setpiece() == 2)
  {
    labels[tk]->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/shoe.png"));
  }
  else if (p[tk]->setpiece() == 3)
  {
    labels[tk]->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/spaceship.png"));
  }
  else if (p[tk]->setpiece() == 4)
  {
    labels[tk]->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/basketball.png"));
  }
  else if (p[tk]->setpiece() == 5)
  {
    labels[tk]->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/ring.png"));
  }
}
```

Should i run another for loop in the constructor after I initialize labels that calls the function setplayerpiece for each instance? Essentially what I want to do is assign each player an image. If I was vague or you need more information please let me know. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Well, first of all you cannot create a `QVector<QLabel>`, since a `QLabel` is a `QObject`, and QObjects are noncopyable; you have to store pointers instead.

Comment: @MatteoItalia okay so `QVector<QLabel*> labels` then I would initialize everything else the same way?

Comment: Your code seems to be convoluted and incomplete. I do not think anyone can properly help with this description. Please try to rephrase it; also, what is `p`?

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach:

```
QVector<QString> playerIconPath;


playerIconPath.append(":/images/hat.png");
playerIconPath.append(":/images/car.png");
playerIconPath.append(":/images/shoe.png");
playerIconPath.append(":/images/spaceship.png");
playerIconPath.append(":/images/basketball.png");
playerIconPath.append(":/images/ring.png");

QVector<QLabel*> labels

for(int i = 0; i < playerIconPath.size(); i++)
{
    labels.append(new QLabel);
    labels[i]->setPixmap(QPixMap(playerIconPath[i]));
}
```

All this can be done inside the constructor if that's what you would like in your design.

Comment: yes that method seems very practical, however, the user selects a piece that corresponds to an integer. I need to assign the piece based on the number they selected.

Comment: So the user is going to choose a number and based on that number a label with a pixmap would be immediately added to the vector?

Comment: yes sort of. The user chooses a number and based off of that number a QPixmap is assigned to a QLabel Vector corresponding to the player. so if played 1 selects a number, the Pixmap would be assigned to the QLabel Vector at index position 0

Comment: edited in changed code, doesnt work complete yet but let me know if I am on the right track

Comment: Ok, I looked at you edited code and I guess I still was not spot on with interpreting you. When I asked "immediately" I thought as soon as the user interacts with the GUI the label choice would be added to the vector. It seems to me if your doing this inside the constructor, it means that the user enters a sequence of numbers and then you create an object which in turn populates the vector of labels. If so, from your last edit I think you're on the right track. What about it isn't working completely yet?

Comment: If you want to link numbers to label you could store them in a std::map/QMap container, in this way you can change the numbering order more easily.